# MPI_Igatherv VS MPI_Isend & MPI_Irecv

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mpich

I have to gather lots of data on my root from other processors at each step of my algorithm, and the size of data at some processors could be zero.

So, I am wondering which method is more efficient and faster to use, MPI_Igatherv, or using (MPI_Isend & MPI_Irecv) when the buffer is not empty.

Does MPI internally take care of zero buffer in MPI_Igatherv?

Is it better and possible to use one sided communication instead of MPI_Igatherv or MPI_Isend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of this you're just going to have to implement it and see what happens.  Implementations can provide a lot of optimizations for different cases.  Network hardware/topology might impact results.

In general, there is nothing wrong with passing zero bytes to a collective operation.  The process contributing zero bytes might still be well-situated (topologically speaking) and could participate in the collective operation.

One-sided operations might be better, or might not.  Depends again on many factors.